# CORS Error, no Access-Control-Origin header, but the header is set

Tags: php, angular, cors

I am trying to make a Post Request to a PHP API, but get the "no Access-Origin-Control header is set on the resource" error, but the header is set. When I make the request with Postman everything is fine and you can see in the Answer that the Header is set.

I already tried to set the header to * but it did not help.

Angular

```
  createUser(formData: FormData) {
      const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        })
      };

      return this.http.post(this.apiURL + 'create_user', formData, httpOptions);
  }
```

PHP

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
/**
 * Creates a User.
 */


require 'database.php';

$cost = 10;
$user = array();
$username=$_POST["username"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$password=$_POST["password"];

$password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ["cost" => $cost]);

$resultCreate = pg_query_params($con, "INSERT INTO wriggling_snakes.users (email, username, password) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)", array($email, $username, $password_hash));
$resultFind = pg_query($con, "SELECT id, username FROM wriggling_snakes.users WHERE wriggling_snakes.users.email='$email'");
if(!$resultFind){
    echo "Error";
}else {
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($resultFind)) {
        $user['id'] = $row['id'];
        $user['username'] = $row['username'];
        $i++;
    }

    echo json_encode($user);
}
```

Postman Answer Headers

Date →Thu, 06 Jun 2019 20:58:13 GMT
Server →Apache/2.4.39 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2r PHP/7.1.29 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
X-Powered-By →PHP/7.1.29
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Allow-Methods →PUT, GET, POST, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers →Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Content-Length →30
Keep-Alive →timeout=5, max=100
Connection →Keep-Alive
Content-Type →text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: *the "no Access-Origin-Control" error* — Quote the complete error message, don't vaguely describe it.

Answer (score 0):

Navigators checks the allowed origins to make a request, so that's why Postman gets the request normally, it doesn't needs them. So, you need to check if PHP is setting the headers correctly because the problem is right there. I'm not sure if you are intercepting the requests with some kind of middleware whit CORS, maybe it can be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]

add this line in .htacess file